# Hi i am trying to get value from the following pattern using python

Tags: python

the corresponding pattern is `('Handmade Frozen Car', 11.0)`. I want to get the value as `11.0`. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: what is the `pattern` in your case, a tuple or ?

Comment: if your variable is `var` take `var[1]` the data type shown above is called tuple

Comment: Please take [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and improve your question with help of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: yes the data type is tuple while calling find or split methods it saya tuple object as no attributes find or split .Then how can i get the value 11 from the above pattern

Answer (score 2):

```
x = ('Handmade Frozen Car', 11.0)
secondElement = x[1]
```

secondElement will be equal to 11.0

Comment: yes it's working thank you